# Divide customers in classes based on the number of purchases and find who belongs in what range?

Tags: mysql, case

I have a table called: `purchases`

```
id |id_customer|id_product|date_of_purchase
1    1             1         2019-03-04
2    2             2         2019-02-05
3    3             3         2019-01-03
4    4             4         2019-01-10
5    5             5         2019-01-02
6    1             1         2019-03-05
7    1             3         2019-03-23
8    1             4         2019-03-23
9    1             3         2019-03-12
10   2             3         2019-03-23
11   2             1         2019-03-11
```

Here is the code I have tried:

```
SELECT id_customer , count(id_customer) as times_bought,  
CASE
    WHEN times_bought < 2 THEN "rare"
    WHEN times_bought >1 and times_bought < 4 THEN "neutral"
    ELSE "frequent"
END
FROM purchases;
```

aside from the fact that the script may have many issues it gives times_bought is not a known column. What do you suggest?

Comment: your sample data looks the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56404690/foreign-keys-cause-duplicate-entry-for-key-primary-in-mysql - perhaps you two should have a conversation.

Comment: I suggest you rewrite this using aggregate functions. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html. AND please add your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a subquery for obtain the count and then join with your main select

```
select  id_customer
   , t.times_bought
  , CASE
    WHEN t.times_bought < 2 THEN "rare"
    WHEN t.times_bought >=2 and t.times_bought < 4 THEN "neutral"
    ELSE "frequent"
    END
from purchases 
INNER JOIN (
    select  id_customer , count(date_of_purchase)  times_bought
    from  FROM purchases
    grouo by id_customer
  ) t on t.id_customer = purchases.id_customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `group by` and checking `count()` instead of `times_bought` (which is not allowed) in the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT id_customer, count(date_of_purchase) as times_bought,  
  CASE count(date_of_purchase)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'rare'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'neutral'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'neutral'
    ELSE 'frequent'
  END customerclass
FROM purchases
GROUP BY id_customer
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w1Gv65EgFQQ28uS8WzmTnm/0).
Results:

```
| id_customer | times_bought | customerclass |
| ----------- | ------------ | ------------- |
| 1           | 5            | frequent      |
| 2           | 3            | neutral       |
| 3           | 1            | rare          |
| 4           | 1            | rare          |
| 5           | 1            | rare          |
```